# Publish nan to a jointState topic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to publish a jointState message from terminal with NaNs as the values inside some of its fields. Is there a way I can do that.

If I do

```
rostopic pub -r 2 /test sensor_msgs/JointState "header:
  seq: 0
  stamp: {secs: 0, nsecs: 0}
  frame_id: '/test'
name: ['l', 'r']
position: [0.0, 0.0]
velocity: [0.0, 0.0]
effort: [nan, nan]"
```

I get the following error

```
Unable to publish message. One of the fields has an incorrect type:
  <class 'struct.error'>: 'required argument is not a float' when writing '/test'
```

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275681/publish-nan-to-a-jointstate-topic/) by [Tanvir](https://answers.ros.org/users/22604/tanvir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-11-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS uses YAML for this, and according to the [YAML 1.1 Reference card](http://www.yaml.org/refcard.html) the value should be `.NAN` (all caps, with the dot):

> ```
> Language Independent Scalar types:
> ```

```
  ...
  [ .inf, -.Inf, .NAN ]    : [ Infinity (float), Negative, Not a number ]
```

The following seems to work for me:

```
rostopic pub -r 1 /some_topic std_msgs/Float64 '.NAN'
```

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5